# How to create a DotNetNuke installation package with custom data, modules, and skins

Tags: installation, package, dotnetnuke

I have a need to create my own DNN installation package that will include my custom modules and skins along with pages and sample data.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can setup the site how you want it (with the pages and sample data), and then Export a Portal Template from the Host -> Portals/Sites page.

Then, when you create a new site, add that template to the `Portals/_default` folder (alongside `Default Website.template`), and you can select that template when installing the site.  Make sure that you also include the packages for your custom modules and skins in the corresponding folder (`Module` or `Skin`) in the `Install` folder.

In terms of sample data, only data in "portable" modules will be included in the template.  This includes the HTML module.  If you need sample data to come along with your custom modules, your business controller class will need to implement [`IPortable`](http://dnn.byteblocks.com/dnnapi/html/T_DotNetNuke_Entities_Modules_IPortable.htm).

Comment: has covered it well, that is how dotnetnuke manages it's own default modules and data.  The only thing I will add is that you may, if you choose, replace the Default.website.template and .resources files for an even easier install experience.

Comment: this thing keeps deleting @bdukes as the first word in my above comment.